# CLP optimization package

Tags: optimization

I just want to implement an optimization problem with CLP ( it solves the linear program), but I haven't found any documents about how can implement an optimization problem by CLP. Does there exist any person to help me to solve my problem?

Thanks

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: https://projects.coin-or.org/Clp#Documentation

Comment: I use c++ language.

Comment: I actually saw this page but it didn’t help me about how can I implement my problem